# Найти повторяющиеся списки в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть массив

```
mylist = [[1,'a'], [2, 'b'], [[1, 'a'], [3, 'c'], [2, 'b']]
```

Из него я хочу получить

```
newlist = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

То есть найти все повторяющиеся списки и закинуть их в массив, пробовал делать так

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [[1,'a'], [2, 'b'], [[1, 'a'], [3, 'c'], [2, 'b']]
[k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1]
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
unhashable type 'list'
```

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://repl.it/repls/ScornfulHeavyVirtualmachines), https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/13970074

Comment: да, это сработает на этом примере, но этот массив был для примера, в реальности он больше и разнообразней на данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать вашим способом, если преобразовать `list` в `tuple`, которое уже hashable, а после его обработки через `Counter` - обратно в `list`:

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [[1,'a'], [2, 'b'], [1, 'a'], [3, 'c'], [2, 'b']]
[list(k) for k,v in Counter(map(tuple, mylist)).items() if v>1]
```

На выходе:

```
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

Заметьте, что у вас лишняя `[` в середине списка, из-за которой ваша ошибка не воспроизводится, а получается другая ошибка. Ну, либо у вас не хватает завершающей `]` и тогда это немного другая задача - надо сначала ещё вложенные списки развернуть.